# Clustering the data based on multiple attributes (in python)

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset describing various cities and some attributes defining each city. I have more or less 10,000 cities and roughly 10 different attributes, some have values from 0-1, some are just numbers that represent the attribute (for example how many parks or hospitals there are in a given city).

I want to cluster this data, so cities that have similar values of attributes (OVERALL) are clustered together.

I was thinking to use k-means algorithm, but I am not sure if that's the best option for my problem/dataset, given that there are also hierarchical clustering and spatial clustering techniques.

#### **Would someone have a recommendation on which alg would be the best to use in this particular case and how to do it quickly in python?**

First 10 rows of the 10,000 row dataset look like this (more or less):

```
columns = ['city_id', 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4', 'attribute5', 'attribute6', 'attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']
data = [[0, 20, 45, 0.15, 0.04, 12, 1, 2, 10, 0.02],
        [1, 12, 35, 0.12, 0.03, 10, 0, 4, 5, 0.04],
        [2, 14, 28, 0.09, 0.01, 8, 1, 5, 4, 0.05],
        [3, 5, 17, 0.08, 0.02, 6, 1, 10, 3, 0.01],
        [4, 35, 36, 0.04, 0.02, 5, 1, 3, 15, 0.035],
        [5, 2, 12, 0.13, 0.04, 7, 0, 4, 13, 0.044],
        [6, 23, 52, 0.19, 0.04, 14, 0, 5, 9, 0.057],
        [7, 42, 29, 0.04, 0.05, 9, 1, 2, 7, 0.024],
        [8, 9, 34, 0.21, 0.07, 10, 1, 6, 15, 0.017],
        [9, 4, 41, 0.22, 0.03, 2, 0, 8, 11, 0.065]]
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually sounds like a prototypical case for k-means clustering. Make sure to normalize the values of the different attributes beforehand though, in order to have the clustering apply equal weight to each.

You could do sth like

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
x = df.values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
kcluster = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(x_scaled) #for 2 Clusters
```

You can then access the clustering with the object returned by KMeans.fit, e.g.

```
kclust.labels_
```

Shows the labels

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. May I ask why do you say this is a typical kmeans case? 
I am asking because I know that for kmeans I have to decide in advance the number of clusters, and I see it as a shortage to be honest...

Comment: I agree in that it is a drawback of the method, but you can circumvent it by trying out different numbers of clusters (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set)). K-means has the obvious advantages that come with being the most popular option (well understood, researched, implemented and documented. So I would suggest, you use it as a starting point and if you're unsatisfied, look at other methods.

Comment: ok, got it! yeah, I am trying to visualize the clusters with matplotlib but I get a weird plot. what you suggested is giving me only the label for each city, instead of a plot. should I first scale back the data to the original values?

Comment: You could try scatter plots with two selected variables and have the points colored using the labelling, sth like 
plt.scatter(df['attribute 1'], df['attribute 2'], c=kclust.labels_)
In case you want to assess the quality of the clustering, you could think about doing a scatter plot with the 2 coordinates being the first 2 scores (the values of the cities projected onto the first two principal components of the data set.

Comment: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) for clarification